# cannot get react-autocomplete item selection to trigger location change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete

I am using https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete for easy navigation in my webapp. My usage is similar to the example seen here: https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete/blob/master/examples/async-data/app.js

I want the browser to open a certain url (in the current window) when the user selects an item of the autocomplete.

My code for this looks like this:

```
onSelect={(value, item) => {
  const url = "/customer/" + item.id;
  //alert(url);
  window.location = url;}
}
```

When an item is selected in the autocomplete `(via cursor keys + enter key)`, the browser does not open the new url, which would be expected. Instead, the browser reloads the current page and adds a question mark at the end of the url.

The weird thing is: When I place an `alert(url)` before the `window.location` assignment, it works (the browser shows the alert first and then indeed opens the new url).

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: do you see any errors in the console ?

Comment: there are no errors visible in the console

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it, the react component was contained also a from. So hitting enter triggered a form submit in addition to triggering the onSelect callback.